# AVR-GCC Compiler not in toolchain list eclipse

Tags: eclipse, avr-gcc, winavr

I'm trying to program in C for arduino and I'm trying my very best to avoid having to use Atmel Studio

- I've installed the AVR plugin for eclipse on the MARS release.
- I've downloaded and extracted WinAVR (and added it to PATH)
- In Eclipse preferences under AVR/Paths, all paths are correctly recognised

but the `New C/C++ Project Wizard` doesn't show AVR-GCC in the toolchain list, not on project type executable, not on AVR Cross Target Application project type, not even when `Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform` is unchecked.

I also have MinGW in PATH for normal C applications.

Is there any way to fix this? (as in, get AVR-GCC in the toolchain list). A friend on linux (I'm on Win10) did get AVR-GCC in his toolchain list without issues on the same eclipse version.